# Setting Nodejs cookie after login is not working

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a NodeJS Express application. For cookies i am doing this

```
var signin = require('./routes/signin');
var appMgmt = require('./routes/app-mgmt');

app.use('/signin', signin);
app.use('/api/secure/app', appMgmt);

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
var server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server,{
  cors:{
    origin: "*"
  },
  allowEIO3: true
});
app.use(cors());
```

After successful login i am returning this

```
      res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true,maxAge: 86400000 });
      res.status(200).send({userId: data._id, email: body.email, accessToken: token});
```

and once I get the response back in client, i am doing this

```
window.location.replace("home");
```

Problem is i dont see any cookies is getting created:

[image]

```
app.all('/api/secure/*', function(req, res, next){
  log('Applying API authentication ...');
  var cookies = JSON.stringify(req.cookies);
  log("Reques content", cookies);
```

`req.cookies` returns `{}`

Comment: Can you add the route handler with which you are sending it? And, are you allowing headers and CORS? Is there any error encountered?

Comment: Also, you can Try `httpOnly: false`.

Comment: i am using CORS. I updated my question

Comment: Doesn't secure: true only work for https?